# Correct usage of wx.DirDialog's GetPaths() with DD_multiple style?

Tags: wxpython

I've been working on a program for few days, and in it I want to allow my user to select multiple directories. I was using wxpython to make my program, and found out wx.DirDialog's GetPaths() method could possibly make this work.

But instead what I kept getting was 'None', and I am not either quite sure what an 'array path' is, nor what to fill in at the parameter of this method.

What I want instead is a list of paths selected by the user.

This is the link to the specific method description, in the Class API page: https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.DirDialog.html#wx.DirDialog.GetPaths

It just says:

```
GetPaths(self, paths)
    Fills the array paths with the full paths of the chosen directories.

    Parameters
        paths (list of strings)–

    New in version 4.1/wxWidgets-3.1.4.

    Note: This function should only be used with the dialogs which have DD_MULTIPLE style, use GetPath for the others.
```

Sorry if this is a bad question, but I just seem to lack searching skills to dig deeper than the Class API page about what an 'array path' is. DD_MULTIPLE style on wx.DirDialog seems quite new, and there isn't much to read from on the web.

And also, I am trying to stick to using Window's filedialog system, so any answers using wx.lib.agw.multidirdialog is much appreciated, but I'll pass on that.

Below is my code:

```
def getDirectories(self, event):

    global multipleDir
    global multipleExport

    dirs = []

    dlg = wx.DirDialog(None, "Choose input directory", "", wx.DD_MULTIPLE | wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST)

    if dlg.ShowModal() != wx.ID_OK:
        print("You Cancelled The Dialog!")
        dlg.Destroy()
        return

    paths = dlg.GetPaths(dirs)

    print(paths)

    dlg.Destroy()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: wxDD_MULTIPLE: Allow the user to select multiple directories. This flag is only available since wxWidgets 3.1.4  - So check that.

Comment: Nope - checked version using `pip show WxPython`, and it tells me I've got wxPython 4.1.1, and that method should work with wxPython 4.1 or better. But thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: wxWidgets is `not` wxpython. On Linux, wxWidgets packages are available in system repositories under the name "wxGTK". On other platforms you'll have to do some digging yourself.

Comment: Did not know that, and thank you. Done some searches, and have found out I've got wxWidgets 3.1.5. I'm currently on windows, so I'm not sure if I could find the "wxGTK" repositeries, but I'll look for it and also do some more research. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you supposed to use `dirs`, not `paths`?

If this doesn't work neither then, considering that the equivalent C++ code in wxWidgets dialogs sample (see the code around [this line](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/c3b232dcfd25107903e0447b36794aab9242c99f/samples/dialogs/dialogs.cpp#L1991)) works fine, it would mean that there is something wrong with wrapping this function in Python and you should try reporting this as a bug if it hasn't been done yet.

Comment: Nope - tried some like ```print(dlg.GetPaths(dirs))```, but it seems like a problem with the 'Array Strings'. There's a whole data type(wxArrayString) in the link you've shown me, whereas wxPython seem to have none of those - or maybe I haven't just found a way to use it yet. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for a fix:

```
if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
     allPics = dialog.GetPaths()
     self.photo_txt.SetValue(allPics[0])
     self.load_image()
```